# Identify Script Causing Memory Leak

Tags: powershell

I have about 100 powershell scripts running on a server and after 9 days without a restart, the memory usage by powershell jumps to 99% of the machine.  This occurs regularly.  I'm looking for a way to identify which script is the culprit to verify that all of the objects are disposed and cleared correctly.

Comment: Some peer review of the script may point to something obvious as well. Perhaps you are loading XML into memory for example, and not cleaning it up? (ie. [xml]$xml = gc some/big/doc.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [script](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2015/05/15/get-memory-consumption.aspx).
You can use `remove-variable VarName` (not $VarName) and [System.GC]::collect() to run the Garbagecollector manually. I often use it for freeing space of big hashtables/Array after foreach loops with it.